# Chamar um método do bean do JSF dentro do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf

Gostaria de chamar um método do JSF dentro de meu código em JavaScript. Pois toda vez que ele executar esse método em JavaScript dentro da função chame outro método que esta dentro JSF.

Alguém tem ideia de como se faz isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o framework [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) que contém um componente para isto, segue um exemplo.

```
<h:form>
  <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="msgs" actionListener="#{remoteCommandView.execute}" />

  <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
  <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="rc()" value="Execute" icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
</h:form>
```

Neste componente, `<p:remoteCommand>`, o atributo `name` determina uma função JavaScript em que você pode chamar para executar o método JSF definido no atributo `actionListerner`.

Para mais informações e documentação sobre o componente veja esse [link](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

Comment: Obrigado por responder.
mas nesse caso ai, eu queria chamar esse metodo remoteCommandView.execute dentro de uma funcao do javascrpt.
nao sei se deu para entender.

Comment: Exatamente. Quando você chamar `rc()` estará chamando uma função JavaScript que vai executar o método `#{remoteCommandView.execute}`. Logo, `rc()` pode ser chamado dentro de uma função JavaScript também. Isso que você precisa?

Comment: Sim, fiz um teste aqui, remoteCommand dentro de uma form e ela não chama o metodo rc();

Comment: Pode mostrar como você fez?

Comment: Desculpa a demora em responder, tentei muito e não consegui acabei ficando triste :(.
 <h:form >     
<script src="code.js"></script>  
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{jogosBean.addMissao()}" />
<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="teste()" value="Execute" icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
</h:form>

dentro de um arquivo code.js
 function teste(){
                rc();
            }

Comment: Cara descobrir o problema pq não reconhece o metodo.
quando tem <h:inputHidden dentro do form ele não reconhece o metodo do p:remoteCommand.

Comment: Hum... Bom saber.

Comment: resolvir aqui. o problema é com inputhidden recebe uma lista, entao eu mando uma lista como string e converto no javascript. não sei se deu para entender. mas vlw pela ajuda.